# Check if viewing teaser in hook_node_access

Tags: views, hooks, users, nodes

Is there a simple way that I can forcibly allow **everybody** to view **all** teasers no matter what, overriding any other permissions set by Content Access, etc.

I was thinking something like this:

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  if( $op == 'view' && ... viewing teaser ) {
    return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
  }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

and then I would set the module weight really high. But I'm not sure how to check `if viewing teaser`. I would also need Views to respect the access I'm granting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in `hook_node_access`, Drupal does not allow for this so easily. Instead, you could use module Premium Content (https://drupal.org/project/premium_content) and do this in configuration.

Btw., this question has already been answered:
[Show teasers to anonymous visitors but not allow access to the body/node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30630/show-teasers-to-anonymous-visitors-but-not-allow-access-to-the-body-node)